# split a String into colums list in dart-flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, split, examplematcher

How to split this "example#example"
To show like this

like columns
1.example
2.example

```
final String list = data!.list!.split('#').first;
```

> result >>>> example

How to show

```
example
example
```

from `example#example`

Answer (score 0):

You can change list type to var and get rid of `first`

```
String data = "example#example";
var list = data.split('#');
print(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.split('#')` will provide a list. You can loop though item.

```dart
  final data = "example#example";
  final list = data.split('#');
  for (final item in list) { // will print one by one.
    print(item);
  }
  final outPut = list.join(" "); //You can join the list. 
  print(outPut); //example example
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to widget not printing, here's a solution.

```
const String data = "example#example";
final List<String> list = data.split('#');
return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    ...list.map((String e) => Text(e)),
  ],
);
```